# How to select the first observation in a category in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table contains different house IDs(`dataid`), time of observation(`readtime`), meter reading Basic Output

[image]

And the query is as follows Query statement :

```
select *
from university.gas_ert
where readtime between '01/01/2014' and '01/02/2014'
```

I am trying to get only the first observation of each day of all the `dataids` between the time span. I have tried `GROUP BY`, but it doesn't seem working.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row for each unique dataid within the time range, you should use the DISTINCT ON construction. The following query will give you a row for each dataid for each day in the range described in the WHERE clause and lets you extend the range if you want to return rows for each day x dataid combination.

```
select distinct on(dataid, date_trunc('day', readtime)) *
from university.gas_ert
where readtime between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02'
order by dataid, date_trunc('day', readtime) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct ON` could make your query much more simple.. More read in [`Documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

*Definition* :

> Keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given
>   expressions evaluate to equal. Note that the “first row” of each set
>   is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired
>   row appears first.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (meter_value) meter_value,
  dataid, 
  readtime
FROM 
  university.gas.ert
WHERE
  readtime between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02'
ORDER BY 
  meter_value, 
  readtime ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at window functions to help out in this. ROW_NUMBER. 
GROUP the records on the basis of day using date_trunc(ie without the time component) and then rank them on the basis of readtime asc

```
 select * 
   from (
         select *
                ,row_number() over(partition by date_trunc('day',a.readtime) order by a.readtime asc ) as rnk
           from university.gas_ert a
         )x
   where x.rnk=1
```